# Swing key bindings separate file

Tags: java, swing, file, key-bindings

Ok, so here's my query. I've been trying for 2 days to put my key bindings in a separate file and have them work on my main. I'm new to swing and am learning by deconstructing code. however, I can get it to work just fine if I add the code to the same file, but for cleanliness I want to put them all in a separate file by themselves. my problem is it reads no error, but the key binds wont work in the alternate file, I've tried, extends and am playing with components but I know little about. what am I doing wrong any advice? I'm starting with simply trying to have the escape key close the window.

// main code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;



public class S extends bttns{
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel controlPanel;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
       private JLabel statusLabel;
       
      
    
    public S(){
    
          prepareGUI();
          setUpKeyBindings();
          
       }
    
       public static void main(String[] args){
          S  swingListenerDemo = new S();  
          S s = new S();
           key(s);
       }
       private void prepareGUI(){
           
          mainFrame = new JFrame("Java SWING Examples");
          mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
          mainFrame.setLayout(null);

          headerLabel = new JLabel("OY" );
          headerLabel.setBounds(150,150,100,130);
          statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);        
          statusLabel.setSize(350,100);
          
          mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
             public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
                System.exit(0);
             }        
          });    
          controlPanel = new JPanel();
          controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

          mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
          mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
          mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
          mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
       }    

    

}
```

// here's the alternate file...….......................................

```
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;


public class bttns extends JComponent {

    public  bttns() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    

    
    
    setUpKeyBindings();
    }
    
    
    public static void key(JComponent component) {
        Action test = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };
        component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "test");
        component.getActionMap().put("test", test);

    }
    public void setUpKeyBindings() {
          int condition = WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT;
          InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
          ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
          
          


          KeyStroke scape = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE,0);

          
                  
        inputMap.put(scape, scape.toString());
        actionMap.put(scape.toString(), new escAction());


       
       
       
       }
    public class escAction extends AbstractAction{
        @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only [focusable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable(boolean)) components can receive key events.

Comment: First learn some Java basics. 1) class names should start with an upper case character 2) class names should be descriptive 3) you only extend a class when you add functionality to the class. 4) I have no idea why you are creating two instances of the "S" class. *I've been trying for 2 days to put my key bindings in a separate file* - All Swing components create the bindings within the component class itself. The bindings are for the components and belong in the component class since key bindings are used to implement functionality of the component.

Comment: If you want to create a reusable `EscapeAction` then check out: [Closing An Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for an example of creating an Action to be shared by any application. By defining the "accelerator", the key bindings will be built for you automatically when you add the Action to a menu item.

Comment: @VGR `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` will allow key bindings to be executed when the window itself has focus, unlike `KeyListener`

Comment: thank you everyone, your input has helped. i will check out the closing an application link and consider reverting back to key listeners. thanks again